# how to make required true , only if the user is certin value?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

hi am making models for my mongodb , and when validating i want the birthday to be required only if the user being added is a student
so i if the user is teacher it is fine if no birthday is provided

```js
const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
 20 
 21         _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
 22 
 23         firstName: {
 24                 type: String,
 25                 required: [true, 'the firstName is missing'],
 26                 validate: [(val) => validator.isAlpha(val, ['fr-FR']), 'not valid first name'],
 27         },
 28         lastName: {
 29                 type: String,
 30                 required: [true, 'the lastName is missing'],
 31                 validate: [(val) => validator.isAlpha(val, ['fr-FR']), 'not valid last name'],
 32         },               
 33         birthday: {      
 34                 type: Number,
 35                 required: [true, 'birthday is missing']
 36                 validate: [(val) => 
 37         phoneNumber: {             
 38                 type: String,      
 39                 required: [true, 'the phoneNumber is missing'],
 40                 unique: [true, 'phoneNumber already in use'],
 41                 validate: [(val) => validator.isMobilePhone(val,['ar-DZ']), 'not valid phone number'],
 42         },                         
 43         email : {                  
 44                 type: String,      
 45                 required: [true, 'the email is missing'],
 46                 unique: [true, 'email already in use'],
 47                 validate: [validator.isEmail, 'not valid email'],
 48         },
 49         password: {
 50                 type: String,
 51                 required: [true, 'the password is missing'],
 52                 minlength: [10, 'error when generating a password for the user'],
 53         },
 54         role: { 
 55                 type : String,
 56                 "enum" : ['teacher', 'student'],
 57                 required : [true, 'the user `s role is missing'],
 58         },
```

Answer (score 1):

The `required` property [can also accept a function](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schematype_SchemaType-required).  For example:

```
required: [
  function () { return this.role === 'student'; },
  'birthday is missing'
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function to validate the value of the `role` and use it as a *boolean* value in `required` property.

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var userSchema = new Schema({
    _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    firstName: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'the firstName is missing'],
        validate: [(val) => validator.isAlpha(val, ['fr-FR']), 'not valid first name'],
    },
    role: {
        type: String,
        enum: ['teacher', 'student'],
        required: [true, 'the user `s role is missing'],
    },
    birthday: { type: Number, required: [isBirthdayRequired, 'the birthday is missing'] },
});


function isBirthdayRequired() {
    if (this.role === 'student') {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```